# Using Keydown Event in Datagridview and Navigation Keys

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am developing an application, I am having trouble incorporating Datagridview Keydown event to perform the same functionality as the Datagridview CellContentClick event. Is it possible to call the CellContentClick event inside the keydown event? If not is there any better way to solve this problem.

Another thing, How can I use the arrow keys to navigate each record in the datagridview? Everytime I run the program when I press the down arrow key it will go to the last record in the datagridview.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code in a subroutine and call the `sub` on both the `keydown` and `cellcontentclick` events.

as for the next question, there is something wrong with the events involving your datagridview. If you could provide more details about the subroutines involving your datagridview, that would be better.